# Starting thread thread with Task class

Tags: concurrency, junit, task, javafx-2

I would like to test my task class that extends javafx.concurrent.Task. I have overriden the call method:

```
   public class myTask extends Task<Void> {
     @Override
     protected Void call() throws Exception {
       while(!isCancelled()){
         doSth();
       }
       return null;
     }
   }
```

then I want to test the invocation of that method with a JUnit test:

```
public class MyTaskTest {
   @Test
   public void testCall() throws Exception {
     MyTask task = new MyTask();
     Thread th = new Thread(task);
     th.start();
     //.... further validation
   }
}
```

but that does nothing. There is no execution of the call method in the started thread.  Could somebody explain why it is the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JUnit test will not wait for your task thread to do what it needs to do and will terminate as soon as the JUnit thread is done. You can see the behaviour with a simple example:

Tested Class:

```
public class Test1 implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("I'm tired");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        }
        System.out.println("I'm done sleeping");
    }

}
```

Test Class:

```
public class Test1Test {
    @Test
    public void testRun() {
        Test1 task = new Test1();
        Thread th = new Thread(task);
        th.start();
        boolean yourTestedStuff = true;
        assertTrue(yourTestedStuff);
    }
}
```

You will see that when you run the test, it only prints "I'm tired" but not "I'm done sleeping" (it might even not print "I'm tired" depending on how threads interleave).

What you can do is wrap your task in a runnable with some form of synchronization with the jUnit thread, for example via a CountDownLatch, for example:

```
@Test
public void testRun() throws InterruptedException {
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final Test1 task = new Test1();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() { //wrap your task in a runnable

        @Override
        public void run() {
            task.run();  //the wrapper calls you task
            latch.countDown();  //and lets the junit thread when it is done
        }
    };
    Thread th = new Thread(r);
    th.start();
    assertTrue(latch.await(1000, TimeUnit.SECONDS)); //force junit to wait until you are done
    boolean yourTestedStuff = true;
    assertTrue(yourTestedStuff);
}
```